# iOS 13 App Crashing on back button UIPrintPanelNavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, printing, ios13, uidocumentinteractioncontroller

iOS App is crashing on when click on printer screen back button.

opening a PDF file by help of UIDocumentInteractionController.
Then clicking on print button on right bar navigation item.
then click on select printer screen,when click on back button on select printer screen, App crashed.PFA the screen shots.

```
documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: urlVal)
documentController.delegate = self
documentController.presentPreview(animated: true)
```

The crash log:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Override of
>   -navigationBar:shouldPopItem: returned YES after manually popping a view controller
>   (navigationController=)'

Comment: What does the crash log say?

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Override of -navigationBar:shouldPopItem: returned YES after manually popping a view controller (navigationController=<UIPrintPanelNavigationController: 0x7f835895a000>)'
[UINavigationController _popNavigationBar:item:] + 379
 5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46eb5fd9 -[UINavigationBar _sendNavigationPopForBackBarButtonItem:] 
[_UINavigationBarContentView __backButtonAction

Comment: I'd suggest to fully add it as a part of the question.